# SetPrecision within Block

Tags: numerics

I am reading Mathematica Cookbook, chapter 1.

Author gives two examples, with the following explanation

> You can control precision within a complex calculation (without using
>   `N[]` on every intermediate result) by changing these values; however,
>   you should only do so within a `Block` (a local context). For example,
>   compare the difference between a calculation with automatic precision
>   for intermediate results to the same calculation with fixed precision
>   (obtained by making `$MinPrecision == $MaxPrecision` ).

```
In[1]:= SetPrecision[(1 + Exp[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]])/2^25, 32]

Out[1]= 7.226780742612584668840452114476*10^-7

In[2]:= 
   Block[{$MinPrecision = 32, $MaxPrecision = 32}, 
     SetPrecision[(1 + Exp[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]])/2^25, 32]]

Out[2]= 7.2267807426125846688404521144759*10^-7
```

Why two results are different, despite the fact that precision was set to 32 digits in both expression ? And what is "automatic precision" ?
Edit:
user "rcollyer" points out that

> running `Precision` on the two results gives 31.5935 and 32..

Answer (score 13):

I don't think that `SetPrecision[x,p]` simply returns a version of `x` with precision `p`.  Rather, it sets all numeric types in `x` to precison `p` and then evaluates `x`.  This is important, if we want `SetPrecision` to work on symbolic arguments.  For example,

```
SetPrecision[2 x, 4]
```

2.000 x

Thus, the following computation need not yield 4:

```
Precision[SetPrecision[Sqrt[2], 4]]
```

4.30103

In fact, this is equivalent to

```
Precision[Sqrt[SetPrecision[2, 4]]]
```

4.30103

Of course, `Sqrt[SetPrecision[2, 4]]` is subject to [precision tracking](http://www.wolfram.com/technology/guide/NumericalPrecisionTracking/) using [significance arithmetic](http://www.wolfram.com/technology/guide/SignificanceArithmetic/).  Thus, we don't expect it's precision to be 4.

On the other hand, setting `$MaxPrecision==$MinPrecision` forces all results to have this common value.

Comment: why is `Precision[SetPrecision[Sqrt[2], 4]]` results in precision different than 4 ???

Comment: @newprint I added one line.  Does that help?

Comment: SetPrecision does just as you claim (so you can remove the "I don't think that" part if you like).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau and Mark, what about `Precision[Sqrt[SetPrecision[100, 10]]]` not returning the same result as `Precision[SetPrecision[Sqrt[100], 10]]`?

Comment: @Rojo It would be easier to answer if you stated why you beleive they should be equal (or whatever expectation they did not meet). The second is clearly going to be 10 up to machine epsilon or so. That's because you set it and immediately evaluated it. The first sets the precision of the argument of Sqrt. The precision of the result will then depend on first order estimates of error of Sqrt, evaluated at 10.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I had understood from the post that something like `Precision[SetPrecision[Sqrt[2], 4]]` is equivalent to `Precision[Sqrt[SetPrecision[2, 4]]]`, so I assumed it would also be the case for `Sqrt[100]`

Comment: @Rojo You have destroyed my day. Okay, I'll make inquiries...

Comment: @Rojo I'm dense today. SetPrecision simply sets precision of numbers it encounters, then lets evaluation proceed. Since Sqrt[100] evaluates to 10, all SetPrecision sees is 10, not Sqrt[100]. So it sets precision to 10, say, and Precision then reports that. For 2 it sees Sqrt[2], and we in effect have Precision[Sqrt[SetPrecision[2,10]]]. Upshot: my first explanation was incorrect as it did not correctly account for SetPrecision semantics.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I shouldn't ask questions when I have slept 5 hours. Thanks a lot!